# Are Primary Keys Recommended on a Timescale Hypertable?

Tags: timescaledb, primary-key-design

I am about to receive timeseries data for some devices placed remotely and have decided to use Timescale hypertables to store the data.

The data consists of:

- device_id
- timestamp
- value

None of the fields can be expected to be unique (The same device could make two measurements at the same time).
The queries would normally be filtered by device_id + timestamp.

In a traditional relational database I would never create a table without a primary key, but in the documentation [Creating your first hypertable](https://docs.timescale.com/getting-started/latest/tables-hypertables) they do not create a primary key.
Would there be any benefit/drawback in adding an id column backed by a Postgres sequence?

I have searched the documentation, but could not find any specific discussion on hypertables and primary keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no requirement to find or operate on individual readings (which it sounds like you don’t) then adding a serial PK for the sake of it is just a waste of space.

The non primary key index you have should be influenced by your query patterns - by default you’ll get `timestamp DESC` but you’ll probably want to add `device_id` to that.

Answer (score 0):

Timescale hypertables do not support primary keys.

This is because the underlying data must be partitioned to several physical PostgreSQL tables. Partitioned look-ups cannot support a primary key.

In your case you can use a "synthetic" primary key of together unique columns `(device_id, timestamp)`.

Answer (score 0):

`create_hypertable` will per default automatically create indexes: see [Hypertable Indexes](https://docs.timescale.com/use-timescale/latest/hypertables/about-hypertables/#hypertable-indexes)

- in the doc example, they pass `time` as index column

When you also have a partition column (`device_id`), you should  [Create a unique index on the hypertable](https://docs.timescale.com/use-timescale/latest/hypertables/hypertables-and-unique-indexes/#create-a-unique-index-on-a-hypertable)